# widget to show country name and time

Tags: android, timezone, widget, android-toast, countries

I want to create a widget which show different countries name and there time in a list can anyone tell how to do this.
And if someone click on the list item it will show a toast with the name of item clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should learn from any example how to create simple widget, next u should implement the listView or recyclerview with country name. U can get them use JSON, or make the list in application using aray-list on xml files or String[] with country names. Next u should do something lile
a) get position on cicked item
b) make toast with something like "You select count" +clickedPosition.

Or yea. Spinner will be the best. U can also check https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html

Answer (score -1):

Spinner is waiting for you https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html

To show both countries name and time, you should create your own drop-down layout to show 2 textview(country name, time) on each item.